# How to add custom field in Magento Upsell Grid?

Tags: magento, catalog

can anyone know how to add custom field in magento upsell grid and after saving the product, how to get the value (Yes/No) for that field?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the product attribute is set to appear in product listings.

Then you should be able to call it using a simple call.

```
<?php
if($_link->getAttributecode() == 1) echo 'Yes';
else echo 'No';
?>
```

This theory is not tested though.